# Не выходит у Данилы-мастера каменный цветок, как он(?) не(?) тужься

Tags: орфография, стилистика

> Не выходит у Данилы-мастера каменный цветок, как он не тужься.

Вот такой пассаж обнаружил в тексте известного блоггера.
Или я чего-то недопонимаю, или тут ошибка на ошибке... Разных, правда, уровня и категории.
Что думаете?

Comment: Наверно, надо переделать в "как бы он не тужился". Тогда, если мы рассказываем историю о нём и представляем себе тот момент, так будет нормально, на мой взгляд. То есть не хватает сослагательного "бы" и прошедшего времени, ему сопутствующего.

Comment: И еще НЕ на НИ поменять.

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой  *надо переделать в "как бы он не тужился"*. - вы точно подметили суть моего недоумения (одного из), но но вот ваше предложение никак не могу принять. Во-первых, мне интересна не переделка, а грамматика, Что здесь не так - и почему. а во-вторых, в вашем версии-то версии тоже не все чисто. НЕ и НИ - это вам уже сказали. Но "бы"-то у вас зачем?! Тут или "не выходит, как ни тужился" или уж "не выйдет, как бы ни тужился". А у вас какая-то мешанина получилась из этих двух разных смыслов. Нет?

Comment: @АлександрСтрелец  *И еще НЕ на НИ поменять* - это да, но только ли это?!

Comment: @АлександрСтрелец: точно, НИ упустил из виду. Да, Бегемотус, будущее в начале предпочтительнее, вы правы.

Comment: @Артём Луговой: _Да, Бегемотус, будущее в начале предпочтительнее, вы правы._ === Предпочтительнее не будущее, а прошедшее: _Не выходил у Данилы-мастера каменный цветок, как он ни тужился._

Comment: @slava1947  *Предпочтительнее не будущее, а прошедшее* - А вот тут совсем не уверен. Тут другой смысл. Это именно о событиях прошлого. А когда под этим самым Данилой разумеется ныне действующий политик... Прошедшее - вроде как не по контексту получается.

Comment: И уж коли разговор перешел в эту плоскость, давайте с грамматикой уже разберемся. А то предложений по правке много, а мне это не столь интересно, я же не литредактором подрядился, у меня чисто академичексие интересы - о синтаксисе и семантике.

Comment: @slava1947: если даже и прошедшее, то без "бы". А я с ним рассматривал.

Answer (score 2):

Это СПП с придаточным уступительным (относительный подтип). Для связи используются союзные слова в сочетании с усилительной частицей НИ. Особое место среди них занимают союзные слова ***как ни*** и ***сколько ни***, которые допускают значение как **реальной  уступки, так и ирреальной** (предположительной) уступки с частицей БЫ. Кроме того, они описывают как **конкретные (единичные) ситуации, так и обобщенные**/повторяющиеся. Другие союзные слова относятся  преимущественно к ситуациям обобщенным и повторяющимся.

1. Сначала приведем различные примеры  написания заданного предложения, используя сходное  выражение «как он ни старается/как  он ни старался)

(1) Не выходит у Данилы-мастера каменный цветок, как он ни старается.

(2)  Не выходил у Данилы-мастера каменный цветок, как он ни старался.

(3)  Не вышел у Данилы-мастера каменный цветок, как он ни старался.

(4)  Не выйдет у Данилы-мастера  каменный цветок, **как бы** он ни старался.

2. А теперь рассмотрим выражения «как ни старайся, как он ни старайся», которые имеют **обобщенное значение**. Пример из учебника: *В таком шуме, **как ни напрягай слух**, ничего не услышишь.*

Это выражение  можно найти в Нацкорпусе: ***как ни старайся*** – 89 примеров, **как он ни старайся** – 4 примера.  Из них видно, сочетание требует соблюдения определенных условий. Мне кажутся правильными следующие предложения:

*Не сделаешь ты, Данила-мастер, каменный цветок, **как ни старайся**.*

*Не выходит каменный цветок, **как ни старайся*** (настоящее время, ситуация изображена отдельно от исполнителя и поэтому в какой-то мере универсальная).  Пример: На таком участке,  как ни старайся, газон расти не будет.

*Не выйдет у Данилы-мастера каменный цветок, **как он ни старайся*** (обобщение, исполнитель назван в обоих частях предложения).

3. **Вывод.**  Таким образом, к настоящему времени (как в исходном предложении) походят два варианта:

*Не выходит у Данилы-мастера каменный цветок, **как он ни тужится**.*

*Не выходит каменный цветок,  **как ни тужься**!*

Первый вариант нейтральный (для конкретной ситуации), а второй с обобщением, как в источнике. Он более экспрессивный, похож на несобственно-прямую речь. Неплохой вариант, я бы его использовала.

В заданном предложении мы видим:  *Не выходит у Данилы-мастера каменный цветок, **как он ни тужься**.* **Вариант некорректный**. Автор хотел применить обобщенную форму, но она не соответствует этому предложению. Почему – я объяснила в ответе. У обобщенной формы **ограниченная сфера применения по грамматике.**

**Приложение**

Примеры из Нацкорпуса с выражением «как он ни старайся»

(1) Актер, даже великий актер, **как он ни старайся**, все же ограничен рамками своей внешности. [Родион Нахапетов. (1998)]

(2) Городу я не враг, он мне  ― тем паче, я б и жить в нем при нужде выучился, но переделать-то меня ему б не удалось, **как он ни старайся**. [Алексей Иванов. (1982)]

(3) Все-таки в душе его, **как он ни старайся**, останется оттенок чего-то... [Ф. М. Достоевский. (1877)]

(4) Тебе ли любить знатного господина, которому, **как он ни старайся,** должна быть противна твоя нищенская жизнь.  [В. А. Соллогуб. (1841)]

Comment: То есть, если я правильно понял, других ошибок, кроме НЕ вместо НИ вы не нашли?

Comment: Нет, вы меня неправильно поняли, заданное предложение имеет НЕВЕРНУЮ грамматику. Я исправила вывод, чтобы он был понятнее, посмотрите пожалуйста.

Comment: Не заметил изменений по существу, признаться. В любом случае причина моего основного недоумения у вас даже не упомянута. Разговоры про обобщенное значение - это все не тот уровень из-за которого стоит шум поднимать, когда тут есть нечто, что я считаю ляпом абсолютным, на уровне "слетевшей шляпы". Смотрите внимательно на вопрос. Ничего не наблюдаете? Ладно, спасибо. Я попозже напишу все, что сам думаю.

Answer (score 1):

КОММЕНТАРИЙ

Конечно, не очень корректна оценка моего ответа **как  шума,** который не стоило и поднимать,  но всё-таки я отвечу на комментарий, обозначив некоторые основные моменты. Отвечу для людей, которых может заинтересовать эта тема. Собственно говоря,  к ним я всегда и обращаюсь.

**1. Разговоры про обобщенное значение**

Цитирую: *Разговоры про обобщенное значение – это все не тот уровень,  из-за которого стоит шум поднимать.*

Это не разговоры, а терминология, принятая в грамматике. ***Как (он) ни старайся*** – это **ОСОБЫЙ ОБОРОТ**, в котором  используется форма 2 лица. Такая же форма характерна для **обобщенно-личных** предложений, и в данном случае  оборот  имеет тот же обобщенный характер, это его **ОСНОВНАЯ ХАРАКТЕРИСТИКА**.

Повторю еще раз пример из учебника: *В таком шуме, как **ни** **напрягай** слух, ничего **не услышишь**.* Здесь мы видим **согласование по второму лицу**, действие отнесено **к  будущему  времени**. Это норма для ИСПОЛЬЗОВАНИЯ оборота – вывод, предположение, прогноз на будущее.

2. Но оборот **расширяет свое применение**, обретает самостоятельность и используется довольно часто  (в Нацкорпусе 89 примеров). Но подходит он к тем предложениям,  где **не ожидается конфликта форм**, например:  *Нельзя подойти, как ни старайся.  Словами не выразить, как ни старайся. Здесь, как ни старайся, ничего расти не будет. Ничего не выйдет, как ни старайся. Как ни старайся, всё видно.*

Это безличные предложения разного вида или личные предложения, где связь  с  субъектом действия (тем, кто старается) не обозначена. Поэтому верно такое предложение: *Не выходит цветок, **как ни старайся**.*

3. Оборот пытается и дальше расширить область применения, для чего включает в свой состав **личное местоимение он**, отнесенное к субъекту действия в главном предложении.  Но в Нацкорпусе всего 4 примера, где такой оборот применяется,  и это неудивительно –  в нем  уже присутствует **стилистическая погрешность** в виде несочетаемости по лицу.

*Актер, как он ни старайся, не может выйти за свои пределы. Переделать  меня ему бы не удалось, как он ни старайся* (сослагательное наклонение). *В душе его, как он ни старайся, останется оттенок.*

Во всех примерах результат действия отнесен **к будущему времени, это всегда прогноз**: ***Не выйдет** у Данилы цветок, как он ни тужься.*  В настоящем времени его нельзя применить: ***Не выходит** у Данилы цветок, как он ни тужься*. Это и есть ОШИБКА.

4. Здесь  еще одна **стилистическая неточность:** местоимение ***он*** можно отнести к цветку. Сравнить: *Не выйдет у Данилы  **цветочная ваза**, как он ни тужься.* Может быть, это ляп на уровне "слетевшей шляпы"? Да только  при устранении этого ляпа  нужного результата  все равно не достигнешь, так как  оборот не подходит для описания событий в настоящем времени.
5. Но в тексте изображен именно **настоящий момент**: события происходят здесь и сейчас. Вот и остается единственный вариант: *Не выходит цветок, **как  ни тужься!***

Comment: Sharon, великолепный ответ! Согласен полностью!

Comment: Спасибо, Серж! Мне ваше мнение очень дорого.

Comment: Я не оценивал ВАШ ответ как шум. Пожалуйста, не передергивайте. Я говорил о том, что проблемы, которые вы затрагиваете не стоят того, чтобы "шум поднимать" - то есть выносить на всеобщее обсуждение.

Comment: А что касается сути, то никто из участвующих в обсуждении не обратил внимание на мой вопрос в скобках после местоимения. И это мне крайне удивительно. Я реально начинаю сомневаться в очевидности этого ляпа...

Comment: Sharon, Истолкуйте мне, пожалуйста, пример из Пушкина (текст моего ответа) с позиций "обобщенного значения" - как вы его понимаете.

Answer (score 0):

Итак. Судя по всему, других мнений уже не будет.
Но у меня сейчас не так много сил для всеобъемлющего изложения своих соображений.
Поэтому сделаю пока тезисный вариант своего ответа, возможно, будет достаточно. Но если будут возражения по существу, конечно, разовью мысль.

Итак, я вижу тут три грубые ошибки.
*Во-первых.*
*Не выходит у Данилы-мастера каменный цветок, как **он** не/ни тужься.*
Кто ОН? Кто тужился? Цветок? Я бы еще принял, что Данила, будь предложение построено по-другому. "Данила не мог сделать... сколь бы он ни тужился".

Сравните в "Евгении Онегине":

*...Он счастлив, если ей накинет

Боа пушистый на плечо,

Или коснется горячо

Ее руки, или раздвинет

Пред нею пестрый полк ливрей,

Или платок подымет ей.

Она его не замечает,

Как он ни бейся, хоть умри.*
(гл. 8, XX-XXI).
~Тут "он" явно не платок.

Но тут-то у нас "Цветок" еще и грамматический субъект действия, подлежащее.
Вот на этом-то фоне все проблемы "обобщенного значения" кажутся мне мелкими, из-за которых я не стал бы тратить свое и ваше время.
Удивительно то, что эту ошибку в том или ином виде протиражировали все отвечавшие, даже не обратив внимания.

*Во-вторых*
Да, форма императива в переносном значении вполне допустима, особенно в разговорном стиле, это так. Но при этом невозможно конкретность исполнителя с использованием местоимения - и вообще формы обращения.

Единственный пример обратного - Высоцкий "Разбойничья".
*Сколь веревочка не вейся.*
Именно так в черновике-оригинале.  В т.ч. - с НЕ  Остается только гадать, предумышленная ли это ошибка.
Споры на эту тему идут полвека - а воз и ныне там.
См., например, здесь.
http://newforum.gramota.ru/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=5800

Что касается примеров с "как он ни старайся"... В них, как я понимаю, нет той конкретики, которая есть даже у Пушкина. Если именно это имелось в виду у Sharon, то отчасти согласен. Но увы, не нашел ни одного внятного определения самого понятия "обобщенное значение", которым якобы оперирует грамматика. Так что принять как данность не могу. *Впрочем, тут надо еще будет разбираться, но начала все-таки с тем, что "во-первых". см. ниже.*

Ну и *в-третьих*.
Единственное, что из моего списка было отмечено в имеющихся ответах, НЕ тут никак не подходит. Другое дело, что это по смыслу, а по грамматике - кто знает, коли фраза изначально неверная?!
На мой взгляд, то, что говорить о "во-вторых", и тем более о "в-третьих", не разобравшись с "во-первых", не имеет большого смысла. Если фраза грамматически не верна в целом, то можно ли говорить о частных (для этой фразы) правилах орфографии, построенных как раз на том, что фраза грамматически правильна? Не думаю.

Вот три моих претензии к исходной фразе, именно их я хотел (и всё еще хочу несмотря на явную неудачу) проверить коллективным разумом.

(+) Про "обобщенное значение".
Когда я говорил, что все это мелко на фоне основной ошибки, я не имел в виду спорить о терминологии. Но коли уж на то пошло. Насколько "обобщенное значение" глагола - категория не грамматическая, а лексико-семантическая. Почему так "принято в грамматике" - остается совершенно неясным. Ну да ладно. главное даже не это, а то что она требует использования **личных форм изъявительного наклонения**. В отношении императива я бы поостерегся использовать этот термин.
Кстати, не надо смешивать с обобщенный (и обобщенно-личным предложением).

(+)
Справедливости ради.
Вот здесь - единственное пока найденное описание понятия "обобщенное значение", которое можно условно считаь определением.
https://cyberleninka.ru/article/n/osobennost-struktury-obobschennogo-znacheniya-lichnyh-form-glagola-v-paremiyah-opyt-semantiko-grammaticheskogo-issledovaniya/viewer
Но и оно не дает представления о том, что же это такое, поскольку разбор идет не самого понятия, а различий в его лингвистическом (грамматическом) м философском   (семантическом)  наполнении. И второе, семантическое, признается более содержательным. То есть опять не про грамматику.